# Calculating percentage for groups with condition in pandas column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `df` that looks like this ( `% Sales Mix` is my added column which I am trying to modify ) :

```
level_0         category                Sales           % Sales Mix 
group_1         a                       315951          3   
group_1         b                       975246          11  
group_1         c                       1578902         18  
group_1         d                       3222811         37  
group_1         e                       49837           0   
group_1         f                       61689           0   
group_1         g                       2464820         28  
group_1         h = sum([a-f])          6204438         nan 
group_1         i = sum([g-h])          8669259         nan 

group_2         a                       137510          3       
group_2         b                       402660          11  
group_2         c                       877219          25   
group_2         d                       1126418         32      
group_2         e                       20200           0       
group_2         f                       51437           1       
group_2         g                       824972          23         
group_2         h = sum([a-f])          2615445         nan     
group_2         i = sum([g-h])          3440418         nan
```

`Sales` denote the sales for a particular `group` and `category` combination `% Sales Mix` shows the percentage of that mix in `categories = [a, b, c, d, e, f, g]` while the `category = h, i` is a sum of those categories, `h` is a sum of everything but category `g` and `i` is the sum of every category but `h`.

I am trying to calculate the percentage of the `Sales` in each category as well as my added categories `h, i`, since categories `h, i` are sub-totals of the previous categories, they should not be taken in to calculations, I tried:

```
cats = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g']

df['% Sales Mix'] = (df['Sales'] / df[df.category.isin(cats)].groupby(['level_0'])['Sales'].transform('sum')) * 100
```

Which correctly creates the `% Sales Mix` column but not for categories `h, i` as they are subtotals so I take them out of calculations.

How can I calculate the `% Sales Mix` for the categories `h, i`? The `i` column would hold `100%` as that's the sum of all categories while the `h` column would be `(h / i) * 100`